# SQL - Lag to previous distinct value

Tags: sql, database, oracle, toad

Is there a way to modify a `Lag` function to not only go back a previous row, but back to a previous distinct value?

**What is currently happening:**

```
 Job Date      Previous Job Date   
-----------    ---------------- 
06/10/2013             -
06/10/2013         06/10/2013
06/10/2013         06/10/2013
07/16/2014         06/10/2013
07/16/2014         07/16/2014
06/07/2015         07/16/2014                   
06/07/2015         06/07/2015
06/07/2015         06/07/2015
```

**What I want:**

```
 Job Date      Previous Job Date   
-----------    ---------------- 
06/10/2013             -
06/10/2013             -
06/10/2013             -
07/16/2014         06/10/2013
07/16/2014         06/10/2013
06/07/2015         07/16/2014                   
06/07/2015         07/16/2014 
06/07/2015         07/16/2014
```

Right now i'm using

```
Lag(a1."Job Date", 1) over (partition by a1."Employee Number" Order By a1."Employee Number")
```

but this is returning the previous rows record instead of the previous distinct or non-matching record. Is this possible with lag or perhaps a different function?

Comment: And what did you want?

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms used. I don't thin <toad> is relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nifty trick. If you use the range between with "1 PRECEDING" it starts the window at the previous distinct value. Assumes you have some key you want to partition on, but if that's not the case you can just remove the PARTITION BY clause.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/3tPzIiDN

```
create table some_test_data
  (
    id integer,
    job_date date
  );

insert into some_test_data values
  (1, date '2023-06-01'),
  (1, date '2023-06-01'),
  (1, date '2023-06-01'),
  (1, date '2023-07-01'),
  (1, date '2023-07-01'),
  (1, date '2023-07-16'),
  (1, date '2023-07-16'),
  (1, date '2023-07-16');

select s.*,
       max(job_date) over (
         partition by id
         order by job_date
         range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
  from some_test_data s;
```

Or, the equivalent with correlated subquery

```
select t1.*,
       ( select max(t2.job_date)
           from some_test_data t2
          where t1.id = t2.id
            and t1.job_date > t2.job_date
       ) as last_distinct_job_date
  from some_test_data t1;
```

| ID | JOB_DATE | LAST_DISTINCT_JOB_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-JUN-23 | *null* |
| 1 | 01-JUN-23 | *null* |
| 1 | 01-JUN-23 | *null* |
| 1 | 01-JUL-23 | 01-JUN-23 |
| 1 | 01-JUL-23 | 01-JUN-23 |
| 1 | 16-JUL-23 | 01-JUL-23 |
| 1 | 16-JUL-23 | 01-JUL-23 |
| 1 | 16-JUL-23 | 01-JUL-23 |